# Should we be raising the bar on the type and/or quality of questions and answers as a way of filtering out AI assisted or generated content?

Tags: discussion, moderators, ai

There has been a lot of debate in the moderators circles around how to address or deal with AI assisted or generated content. The proliferation and uptake of AI tools has the potential benefit of helping users but also can have negative effects when not used as intended.

As to what people in the community can do in general, I wonder if there is an expectation of moderators to try and raise the bar on the level of quality in the questions or answers provided as one way of managing the communities expectations for the content that we want to see in UXSE.

Or perhaps we should start moving the focus towards less knowledge related type of questions (like what is this UI pattern), and shift into more practical questions that apply the knowledge in a way that AI tools would find difficult to do because it is more context specific and sensitive?

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I hope you'll keep the knowledge type questions, as they often show up in the sidebars of other questions and provide great educational content for novice or occasional UX practitioners.

We incentivize raising flags and it seems that posts are hidden after a certain number of flags are raised automatically (but is that true? Or do the mods have to review each one?) I wonder if there could be another flag for "This is an AI-generated response that does not answer the question."

Comment: A study has been done by a researcher from Stack Exchange (who is no longer around) to measure how reliably humans can detect AI-generated content in fulfillment of the moderator action agreement. A summary of this study suggests that it is not a trivial problem to solve, because there are questions and answers that are equally hard for humans and AI to determine whether it is AI-generated or not. I do come across the flags regularly and it helps, but having a flag specifically for AI-generated content could be helpful as well.

Comment: At some point, AI will be better at generating responses to knowledge type questions (just as chess players have accepted that chess bots have become better at generating chess moves compared to humans), so unless our knowledge of UX design evolves and the fundamental principles of design change, I feel like those types of questions will become less relevant on UXSE (just a personal opinion).

Comment: That crossed my mind as well - AI will sound far more natural and its ability to make good judgements in answering questions will improve over time.